# Python Requests ignoring time outs

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make some kind of a scanner with python (just for fun)

it will send a get request to an random ip and see if there is any answer 
the problem is that every time that the connection fails the program will stop running . 
this is the code

```
import time
import requests


ips = open("ip.txt", "r")

for ip in ips:
    r = requests.get(url="http://"+ip+"/",verify=False)
    print(r.status_code)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

this is what i get by trying just a random ip :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='177.0.0.0', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is throwing an error. To protect against this, use a `try`/`except` statement:

```
for ip in ips:
    try:
        r = requests.get(url="http://"+ip+"/",verify=False)
        print(r.status_code)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('Connecting to ip ' + ip + ' failed.', e) 
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: catching `requests.exceptions.RequestException` would capture more probems.

Comment: Nitpick: Adding `from requests.exceptions import RequestConnection, ConnectionError` would be better for readability.

Comment: @IanAuld - not necessarily. Discarding the namespace leaves future readers guessing which one you are talking about.

Comment: `ConnectionError` inherits from `RequestException` so  you only need the more general one.

Comment: Thanks again @tdelaney